# Curious badge bug

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I saw that it has been already reported that also they have earned courious badge but the badge has not been given. but their answers say that they must wait a day and the badge will be awarded.

In my case its 8/5 and it was 5/5 long time ago and I have never received a message telling that I have earned it. its just telling me that the next badge to be awarded is Curious badge.

this is my profile: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/11815/ashkan-mobayen-khiabani

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why haven't I received the "Curious" badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263351/why-havent-i-received-the-curious-badge) - even though this question is older, that one is worded better and has a screenshot.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you click on the badge in your profile it will tell you that you need a positive question record and that you don't currently have one.

Excerpted from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/67399#67399)

> A positive question record means you don't have too many closed, downvoted or deleted questions, overall. The formula is (total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions >= 0.5. Questions that have been downvoted and closed and deleted count three times in this calculation!

You have [at least one deleted question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/46678/why-were-the-number-of-google-plus-ones-reduced-from-36-to-28-when-i-refreshed), although I can't see whether it's downvoted or not.

Comment: well I have 10 questions, all with positive or 0 votes (13 up votes in total) no down voted, no deleted and no closed question. there is only 1 duplicate

Comment: Only moderators can search for your deleted questions. Almost everyone says they haven't got any but in actual fact they have. If you go here http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/11815/ashkan-mobayen-khiabani?tab=questions there should be a deleted recent questions link at the  bottom of the page but that will (as it says) only show you recent stuff.

Comment: I'm a developer and I have just asked few question at webmasters.stackexchange.com, right now I have been 71 days in a row online in stackoverflow while I barely visit webmasters once in a month. I'm sure I have done nothing but asking and getting the answer and get away. I have not deleted any questions

Comment: yes its deleted by moderator and also closed before deletion. and it has no upvote or downvote and still there should be positive. you know I don't actually care about a bronze medal but I wanted to make sure that there is no bug in the site as I really love and care about the stackexchange collection

Comment: well I said I haven't deleted any question (that still I'm insisting) I didn't know moderators just delete a question that is not spam (it was closed because it was very localized and deleted I think for the same reason)

Comment: All deleted questions you asked count, whether you deleted them or somone else did.

Comment: thanks a lot as I said I thought moderator only delete a question only if it is a spam. Thanks a lot for the nice information

Comment: Users with 10K reputation can delete questions, also negatively voted questions get deleted by the system eventually if they have no answers.

Comment: @RobertLongson Users with 10K reputation can delete any question that is closed but not locked. The question score does not matter. They cannot vote to delete non-closed question.