# Clarify or visualize the parameters involved for receiving the Curious badge

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, badges, badge-progress, asking-days-badges

I was wondering about a question similar to [Why haven't I received the "Curious" badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263351/) (for another site), where my "stats" are currently "**10/5**" (instead of "**13/5**"). The answer from "Shadow Wizard" links to
[Robert's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263352/152859), which links to yet another "[this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256469/curious-badge-bug/256477#256477)". This last answer has some details about the actual calculation (like the "**10**" in my case), which is like so:

> A positive question record means you don't have too many closed, downvoted or deleted questions, overall. The formula is (total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions >= 0.5. Questions that have been downvoted and closed and deleted count three times in this calculation!

Somewhere I also read that these **deleted** questions seem to count for 3.

But the OPer of a deleted question cannot see deleted questions anymore after a while (X days) either. So that seems to make it impossible to actually "verify" your own score (the "**7**" part), and also how many more "good questions" will be needed. In my case, I'm aware (remember) that there has been at least 1 question deleted. So I assume in my case the "7" must become at least "8" (I don't have negative or closed questions), though I doubt that will be sufficient. Also because I have 2 more questions with a zero votes balance (which makes me wonder also how accurate the "total questions" in the above quote really is ...).

**My suggestion**: think of a way to somehow clarify (visualize) the formula quoted above. Or as a variation at least provide some way to find out the exact number of you questions that were ever deleted (not just the recently deleted ones). Or maybe some other type of indication to indicate "how much more good questions are needed to ever receive the "Curious" badge.

**Update**: I recently learned about adding `deleted:yes` to a query. With that, these are some more stats about my questions (using "12345" to represent my user id from the site where this question is about):

- **user:12345 is:q** - results in 14 (not deleted) questions, 11 of them have a positive (> 0) voting balance, none of these 14 are closed.
- **user:12345 is:q deleted:yes** - results in 7 (deleted) questions, with this Status / Voting balance for each of them:

| Question id | Status | Voting Balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Closed | +4 |
| 2 | Duplicate | +2 |
| 3 | Migrated | 0 |
| 4 | Duplicate | 0 |
| 5 | Duplicate | 0 |
| 6 | Closed | -1 |
| 7 | Closed | -4 |

So with that extra info, and as per the "***Questions that have been downvoted and closed and deleted count three times in this calculation!***" I think (guess) in my case the 2 deleted questions with negative voting balance corresponds to -(2*3)=-6 ... So that the "stats" in my case will have to become something equivalent to "(11-6)/5" = "5/5" ... Just guessing, and fingers crossed to see what will happen if I ever post a new question on that site that does not get downvoted+deleted (assuming all other votes for my existing questions don't change in the meantime).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One third of your questions have been deleted. On top of that, two of the deleted ones have negative votes. Assuming "c" were closed (and I bet some were) you have 21 - 2 - c - 7 = 12 - c. If c is 2 or more, this will be 10 or less, and when you divide that by 21 you get less than 0.5. Feel free to substitute a real number for how many were closed.

This stuff about "deleted counts for 3" is just confusing you. The reason deleted questions "count as three" is that you first subtract all your deleted questions (regardless of score, and whether closed or not), then all your negative-score questions (whether open or closed, deleted or not), then all your closed questions (regardless of score, whether deleted or not.) A question that is closed, negative-score, and deleted will get subtracted three times.

To be honest, worrying about the badge and doing SEDE queries when **a third of the questions you asked have been deleted** seems really strange to me. It's like you really know how this system works, but ask incredibly off topic or low quality questions. Worry about that. If you can, improve your old questions. If you can't, make sure the next ones you ask are good. The badge will happen, assuming you don't get question-banned.

Comment: Thank you Kate. About your "14-2-0-7": where does the "2" refer to, is it the 2 questions with negative voting balance? And the "0", is that as per your assumption "none were closed"? Also; is "closed" or "duplicate" equivalent for this calculation? And how does a closed question with a positive voting balance need to be processed? And what about a "migrated" question? FYI: I really do not (repeat: not) ***worry*** about that badge. Instead, the real reason for my question is as in the title it. If you don't know about the 'deleted:yes', it's really challenging, no?

Comment: Aha, **THAT** seems to explain it all ... Somebody should take care of getting your prior comment somehow included in the details of that hard-to-understand rule for that badge ... Anyway: "accept", and merci!

Comment: @KateGregory It is not a half of the questions that are deleted, it is just one third. 7 questions out of the 14+7.

Comment: @wythagoras you're right. It's 21-(2+?)-?-7 and that must come out to less than 11. There may be nondeleted questions with negative scores and there may be questions that were closed before they were deleted. OP must have at least 2 more points taken off that calculation to come down to 10 or less. And a third of your questions deleted is still an awful lot.

Comment: @KateGregory You are absolutely right about the last sentence. Also, I looked at the OP's profile (I will not disclose on which site since the OP hid it) and the first question mark is a zero. There are also no undeleted closed questions. However, I expect that most of the deleted questions are closed.

Comment: I just added some more details about status and votes for the 7 deleted questions. Can you further refine your answer by substituting the value for **c**, taking into account the status of **migrated** and **duplicate** also?

Comment: duplicate is just a close reason. They are all closed. Migrated is just something that happens to questions closed as offtopic if they are lucky enough to be ontopic somewhere else. Therefore c is 7 if none of your nondeleted questions is closed. 5/21 is a long way below 0.5 If you ask 10 questions that stay open, aren't deleted, and don't get negative votes, you will be at 15/31 - still below half. But your eleventh good question, assuming you have no bad ones by then, should take you back into positive territory.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens First of all, I don't understand how my French has to do with answering your question or enhancing this answer. I did look at the weekly rankings, that is how I found your profile. No, I did not notice in any way that you "learned from mistakes". And if it weren't for your massive answer collection, you actually might have been question banned, depending on the order you asked the questions.

Comment: @KateGregory Thanks for the extra clarification. The only thing I still don't get is what the "10" refers to in my current "10/5" status (as shown with my progress indicator of that specific badge). Can't be like "you have to ask at least 10 more 'good' questions, since the past few weeks (with only 'good' questions), it keeps going up with 1 at a time.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but it seems to be "questions with a positive score" / "number of days (max 5) you have asked on". On SO I have 4 questions, three with a positive score and 1 with a zero score, and it reads 3/5. I don't think it attempts to tell you all the details, just one simple number. It could also be "open nondeleted questions with a positive score" - I'm afraid I don't have a sample set to test that against.