# Display positive question record actual number/ratio for user convenience

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, badges

***Personal Opinion***

*Example Badge:* When I click on the [Electoral badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for/188732#188732) (**Picture One**) I can see percentage, but why not on this [Curious badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for/67399#67399) (**Picture Two**)... generally new user are confused by seeing this...

I think *need positive record* can be replaced with "***Ratio***" or "***Number***" as per as requirement with text, etc. for the user's convenience...

***Edit***

***Example Model***

I want to replace (***need positive question  record***) text from (**Picture Two**) with **Example as a =>** ***0.1/0.5 positive question record ratio*** (like the Electoral badge shows **51/25 on question** area)

***End Edit***

From this [How is a“positive question record” calculated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290545/how-is-a-positive-question-record-calculated)

```
(total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions ≥ 0.5
```

**Picture One**

[image]

**Picture Two**

[image]

Comment: Already requested: [Clarify or visualize the parameters involved for receiving the Curious badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276738/clarify-or-visualize-the-parameters-involved-for-receiving-the-curious-badge)

Comment: @Sonic the Curiouser Hedgehogi  think no... this question showing  display board for question record .. this not what I requested ..  I want to show like _0.1/0.5 is positive record_   and like `Electoral` badge