# Is the 'positive question record' a rolling count, and if so how do I work out how many days until it will be positive again?

Tags: support, badges, badge-progress, asking-days-badges

I am '33/30' for the Inquisitive badge, but as I don't have 'positive question record' in the last 30 days, I can't get it yet.

[image: profile showing the pop-over for getting the Inquisitive badge. Under a full progress bar of 33 out of 30 it says 'X need positive question record']

The badge text says:

> Asked a well-received question on 30 separate qualifying days, and have a positive question record

Based on the formula in [How is a "positive question record" calculated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290545/how-is-a-positive-question-record-calculated/290546#290546)

> `(total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions ≥ 0.5`

And [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/229495/progress-towards-curious-inquisitive-and-socratic-badges) I'm not clear how many more days of good questions I need to have.

I'm trying to figure out, assuming the 'total questions' is for the '30 separate qualifying days', that is, it's a rolling score over the 30 separate days, how many more days I need to have a positive (0+ score, not closed, not deleted) question on to bump my 'score' up enough to get the badge?

For instance, say in the last '30 separate qualifying days' I ask 30 questions: the most recent 14 of which are positively received (0+ score, not closed, not deleted) and the first 16 were closed/deleted/negatively scored. My score in theory would be:

```
score = (total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions ≥ 0.5
score = (30 - 0 - 0 - 16)/30
score = 14/30
score = 0.467 
0.5 ≥ 0.467
```

So I would not be considered to have a positive question record for those '30 separate qualifying days'.

Then for the next X days, I ask one positively received (0+ score) question. That would mean on day 30+X, my closed/deleted/negative count is 16-X.

```
score = (total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions ≥ 0.5
score = (30 - 0 - 0 - (16-X))/30
score = 14+X/30
14+X/30 ≥ 0.5
X = 15-14 = 1
```

So, unless I'm mistaken, that means I'd only need 1 day of positively scored questions, as the non-positively received on day 1 is 'removed' from the rolling total of '30 separate qualifying days'?

However, if all of my non-positively received questions are in the later half of the '30 separate qualifying day' period, I wouldn't end up removing even one from the count until after 16 days of positively (0+) scored questions.

How do I figure out, where in this '30 separate qualifying day' window I am, and when the non-positively received questions age off?

Comment: The list of Question badges on [What are the badges I can earn, and what are the criteria?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399/355458) gives an explicit formula for what counts as a "positive question record". You can do some digging into your questions to get some numbers to plug into the formula and solve for the total number of "positive question days" (unfortunately, it's a lot easier with 10k+ rep to find your own deleted questions)

Comment: It sucks having a negative question record :( the only thing that's possibly more frustrating about the badges is finding out about the unsung hero criteria when you've already answered hundreds of questions. That's one of the the reasons I'm not too eager to downvote noob questions, it's bad enough the OP gets -2 on their question record that adding a -3 against the question record will quickly wreck their chances at gaining the curious/inquisitive badges.

Comment: Along with: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290546/282094 there is this question that you might want to vote on:   https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358289/282094

Comment: @bad_coder none of these questions are showing me how long until I can get the badge though only that I don't have it yet. It's also not clear to me, if I asked 30 positively received questions today, if that would counteract a negative question I asked yesterday.or I'd have to wait another 30 days... I might explain my confusion in an edit.

Comment: @Pureferret You are under the impression that just waiting will earn you the badge - it will not. The positive question record has nothing to do with when your last negatively scored question was. It is calculated solely based on your number of questions compared to the number that have been downvoted, closed, and/or deleted, using the formula in the linked question.

Comment: @Pureferret you might have to ask a moderator how many deleted Q/A's you have that aren't visible if you don't have 10k...

Comment: @animuson "You are under the impression that just waiting will earn you the badge" I am not. I'm wondering if, say my last negative question was was 15 days ago, do I need to ask positively answered questions for the next 16 days? Or could enough positive questions asked in less than 16 days work?

Comment: The new questions don't even necessarily need to be positively scored. They just can't be negatively scored, closed, or deleted. Nor do they need to be asked on separate days. Increasing the total number of questions on your account _without_ increasing the number of questions that count against you is one way to improve your ratio. Improving past questions that currently count against you to a pint where they no longer do is another way. The number of days it takes to do that is irrelevant.

Comment: @animuson ahhh, so it's not a positive record *over the last 30 days*. Right that's where my confusion was.

Comment: Not quite. It's a positive record *over your lifetime of asking questions*. The number of days requirement and the positive record requirement are *entirely separate* requirements, calculated using different formulas. For the badge to be earned, you must satisfy both. The first link in these comments explains it clearly.

Comment: @animuson is that any clearer?