# Why is the 'Next badge', Curious, the same as the Newest badge in this profile?

Tags: support, bug, profile-page, badge-progress

[image]

This user (not me) has been awarded the Curious badge. Why is the 'Next badge' still showing as Curious badge on [this profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10138625/chirag-c?tab=topactivity)?

Comment: Don't you have to go and pick the next badge manually? What happens if you haven't done that yet?

Comment: That is right @VLAZ, if you dont manually check the box there it remains showing the current badge

Comment: this not my profile..

Comment: It was a general "you" as in "anybody", not you specifically. And as Luuklag says - once somebody gets a badge, they have to go and pick the next one manually. Until that point, their profile will just display the "next" badge as the one they've already received.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Curious badge bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256469/curious-badge-bug)

Comment: @Sonic the K-Day Hedgehog no.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). This is how that widget looks for the owner (except that this is a different badge):

[image]

Until they've made a choice for which badge to track next, they will be registered as tracking that particular badge. And [this](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/27340/glorfindel?tab=activity) is how their profile will look to others:

[image]

Comment: Has it always been this way? Or only recently? I just noticed it a minute ago (see my answer below: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357527/391772), and searched on Meta to see if someone else had asked about it, then found this page, which happened to be from ***only 2 days ago***. Also congratulations on 699 bronze badges! Only one more to go!

Comment: It has been so for a long while (perhaps at least 4 years?), I don't remember it having changed. Also, your bug is perhaps a consequence of [Why haven't I received the "Curious" badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263351/295232)?

Comment: Good point. I've upvoted one of their questions that had 4 upvotes, so let's see if they get the badge now. It's still a "bug" from a UX or presentation perspective. It seems very incorrect to say: "Progress towards next badge: 6/5"

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

I appreciate Glorfindel's answer and how the system treats this issue "by design" however when we look at [TheSimpliFire's profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/368040/thesimplifire?tab=topactivity) we see this:

[image]

which casual observers will certainly think is a bug.

Comment: TheSimpliFire doesn't have a positive question record. try to click on the badge.

Comment: @ppwater Interesting. There must be some deleted questions with a lot of downvotes. After all: "Meta is Murder". However "Progress towards next badge: 6/5" will not look  "correct" to most observers. It appears more like a bug than anything else.

Comment: Hmm, true. it'll be great if there is not positive question record, don't suggest it or don't make the badge appear or something.

Comment: I think that the person hasn't decided the next badge to track yet. Surprisingly, users don't get notified when they completed a badge.